# The drift current in a $p-n$ junction is $20\mu A$. Estimate the number of electrons crossing a cross section per second in the depletion region

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

***QUESTION:***

> The drift current in a $p-n$ junction is $20\mu A$. Estimate the number of electrons crossing a cross section per second in the depletion region.

***MY CALCULATIONS:***
The drift current is caused due to the movement of free electrons in the opposite direction of the  current and holes in the same direction of the current. The moving holes are essentially electrons moving in the opposite direction. So we can say that the number of electrons crossing a cross section per second in the depletion region due to the drift current is $\dfrac{20\mu A\times 1{\sec}}{1.6\times10^{-19}C}=\dfrac{2\times10^{-5} C}{1.6\times10^{-19}C}=1.25\times10^{14}\text{electrons}$.

But the answer given in textbook is $3.1\times10^{13}$ which is $1/4^\text{th}$ the value I got. Can someone point out my conceptual mistake?

Question reference: Concepts of Physics by HC Verma, Vol II, Chapter $45$,Exercise Question $20$

Comment: If what you quoted is the whole question you were given a bad question. There isnt enough information. You are probably supposed to assume that half of the drift current is electron current and that drift current is all they are actually asking you to estimate. But then you are still missing a factor of 2.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone point out my conceptual mistake?

Holes are not "essentially electrons". They are much more than that physically, and this question assumes you will treat them separately from electrons.